# extract an embedded exe in C# result in a error

Tags: c#, exe

When I click on the button I get an error:
Result: Stream was null
(System.NullReferenceExceoption)

```
private void btScreenshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    string exePath = "c:\\tmp\\adb.exe";    
    ExtractResource("Properties.Resources.AndroidBSPinstaller.adb.exe", exePath);
}

void ExtractResource(string resource, string path)
    {
        Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? It's quite obvious that `stream` is null. So you cannot access `strean.Length`.

Comment: If you share a little more detail about what you want to achieve, maybe someone can tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler for the `btScreenshot_Click` calls `ExtractResource` to try opening a stream from an [embedded resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022) whose full path is:

```
"Properties.Resources.AndroidBSPinstaller.adb.exe"
```

If opening the `stream` is successful (it isn't) then the next line reads the `byte[] bytes` and the line after that copies the byte array to its final destination at:

```
"@c:\tmp\adb.exe"
```

You report that after executing the following line `stream` is null.

```
Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
```

This means that either the resource **adb.exe** never *got* embedded in the binary (so it doesn't exist as a manifest resource stream) *or* sometimes there is a simple typo error in the resource path. Either way, you can debug this by retrieving an array containing the full paths for *all* the embedded resources in the assembly using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()`.

```
void ExtractResource(string resource, string path)
{
    // Check for fully qualified existing embedded resource names
    string[] resourceNames = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Embedded resources in assembly:");
    Debug.WriteLine($"===============================");
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, resourceNames));
    Debug.WriteLine($"===============================");

    if (resourceNames.Contains(resource))
    {
        Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        // NOTE: The OP has confirmed that this line is being hit.
        Debug.Assert(false, $"The path '{resource}' is not an embedded resource");
    }
}
```

Note that valid resource paths will typically begin with the *default namespace* (which of course will be different for your app than mine).

[image: debug output]

Comment: Thanks,
with the check for the embedded resource names I found out that the path was not correct.
the correct path: 
ExtractResource("AndroidBSPinstaller.Resources.adb.exe", exePath);
It was: ExtractResource("Properties.Resources.AndroidBSPinstaller.adb.exe", exePath);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to extract a file from resources

```
public static class ResourceExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a project resource extract to desired location
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="BytesToWrite">Resource</param>
    /// <param name="FileName">File name with extension and path is optional</param>
    public static void FileSave(this byte[] BytesToWrite, string FileName)
    {

        if (File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            File.Delete(FileName);
        }

        var FileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        var BinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(FileStream);

        BinaryWriter.Write(BytesToWrite);
        BinaryWriter.Close();
        FileStream.Close();

    }
}
```

Usage (path is in a TextBox but can easily be changed to any existing folder)

```
private void ExtractButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileNameTextBox.Text))
    {
        Resources.ColorCop.FileSave(FileNameTextBox.Text);
        Process.Start(FileNameTextBox.Text);
    }
       
}
```

Resource in project

[image]

[image]

**Edit**: changed to Embedded resource

[image]

[Full source](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/closet-code/tree/master/ExtractResourceToFile1)